# Custom date and time field on opportunity is mismatching in developer console

Tags: developer-console, timezone

I've a custom Date&Time field on Opportunity.When I retrieve for a single record,this date value is showing correct in Developer console but Salesforce UI is showing wrong date.I'm in EST Time-zone.Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that the UI is not formatting the date for your current Time Zone.

If you're not displaying the date  then the date will show in GMT.

I can recommend a quick way to fix this

Create a component:

```
<apex:component access="global" controller="FormattedDateTimeController">{!FormattedDatetime}
    <apex:attribute assignTo="{!valueToFormat}" description="The DateTime value to be rendered" name="datetimeValue" type="DateTime"></apex:attribute>
    <apex:attribute assignTo="{!definedFormat}" description="The optional format to use for the DateTime value to be rendered" name="datetimeFormat" type="String"></apex:attribute>
</apex:component>
```

Controller:

```
public class FormattedDateTimeController {
    public DateTime valueToFormat { get; set; } //property that reads the datetime value from component attribute tag
    public String definedFormat { get; set;} //property that reads the string value from component attribute tag

    public String getFormattedDatetime() {
        if (valueToFormat == null) {
                return ''; 
        } else { 
            if (definedFormat == null) {
                return valueToFormat.format(); //return the full date/time in user's locale and time zone
            } else { 
                return valueToFormat.format(definedFormat);  //Specify Time zone like IST,CST
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and use it on a page like so:

```
<c:FormattedDateTime datetimeValue="{!pr.runDate}" datetimeFormat="MM/dd/yyyy" />
```